# How to store each word in a string into specific variables?

Tags: php, string, split

Please help me to put these words of string into some specific variables.

```
$remove4 = "First 1st, Second 2nd, Third 3rd, Fourth 4th";
```

i'm using this code, but i can get it right. can somebody tell me what is the problem in my code?

```
    $str = (explode(",",$remove4));

$check = array();
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
    $check[] = $str[$i];
}

foreach($check as $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
    $var=(explode(" ", $value));
        echo $var[0];
        echo $var[1];
}
```

Goal:

```
Process1 = 'First';
Process2 = 'Second';
Process3 = 'Third';
Process4 = 'Fourth';

Temp1 = '1st';
Temp2 = '2nd';
Temp3 = '3rd';
Temp4 = '4th';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$remove4 = "First 1st, Second 2nd, Third 3rd, Fourth 4th";

$str = (explode(",",$remove4));

$check = array();


$i=0; foreach ($str as $value) { $i++;

    $explode = (array_values(array_filter(explode(" ",$value))));

    ${'Process'.($i)} = $explode[0];
    ${'Temp'.($i)} = $explode[1];
}

echo $Process1 . "<br /> ";
echo $Process2 . "<br /> ";
echo $Process3 . "<br /> ";
echo $Process4 . "<br /> ";

echo $Temp1 . "<br /> ";
echo $Temp2 . "<br /> ";
echo $Temp3 . "<br /> ";
echo $Temp4 . "<br /> ";
```

Output :

```
First
Second
Third
Fourth
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
```

Comment: Wow, this what i've been looking for all day.. thanks buddy. I owe you a cup of coffee. :D

Comment: I wont forget your promise of coffe :D

Comment: Mark my word buddy.. :) given an opportunity to visit your beautiful place Turkiye..

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
  foreach($check as $key => $value){
   //echo $value . "<br>";
    $var=(explode(" ", $value));
        ${'Process'.($key+1)} = $var[0];
        ${'Temp'.($key+1)} = $var[1];
}
```

echo $Process1;
echo $Temp3;